# SQL QUERY- multiple COUNT returns wrong (same) results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

how to combine this two queries without giving me the same output ?

the first query is :

```
select   vwemployee.directorateName   , count(vwemployeeCourse.employeeId) as t1 

from vwemployee , vwemployeeCourse 

where  vwemployee.directorateName = vwemployeeCourse.directorateName 

GROUP BY vwemployee.directorateName
```

this is the second query :

```
select vwemployee.directorateName , count(vwemployee.directorateName) as t2 

from vwemployee , employeeCourse

where vwemployee.Id = employeeCourse.employeeId 

GROUP BY  vwemployee.directorateName
```

i will be using the combined query to generate a report

the first column is the name of the directorate

**by the way when i combined them my self t1 had the same result as t2 but when they are separate it gave me the right result**

> the t1 column should display how many courses this specific
>   directorate took , and t2 column should display how many employee's
>   under this directorate took this courses
>
> **so the total columns of the table of the combined query should be 3 columns**

Comment: Do you really have both a `VWemployeeCourse` and an `employeeCourse` table?  or is that just a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are purposely using a employeeCourse instead of vwemployeeCourse in the second query I would use the following.  I use a full outer join in case some directorates are in one table/view and not the other.  If it is a typo and the name should be the same in both queries an inner (regular) join would work.

```
With cteQuery1 As
(
Select   vwemployee.directorateName   , Count(vwemployeeCourse.employeeId) as t1 
    From vwemployee 
    Join vwemployeeCourse On vwemployee.directorateName = vwemployeeCourse.directorateName 
    Group By vwemployee.directorateName
)
Select cteQuery1.directorateName, t1, t2
    From 
        (
        Select vwemployee.directorateName , Count(vwemployee.directorateName) as t2 
            From vwemployee
            Join employeeCourse On vwemployee.Id = employeeCourse.employeeId            
            Group By  vwemployee.directorateName
        ) Query2
    Full Outer Join cteQuery1 On cteQuery1.directorateName = Query2.directorateName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUM(IF())`:

```
SELECT vwemployee.directorateName, 
    SUM(IF(vwemployee.directorateName = vwemployeeCourse.directorateName),1,0) directorateCount,
    SUM(IF(vwemployee.Id = employeeCourse.employeeId),1,0) idCount,
    FROM vwemployee , vwemployeeCourse 
    WHERE  vwemployee.directorateName = vwemployeeCourse.directorateName 
        OR vwemployee.Id = employeeCourse.employeeId
    GROUP BY vwemployee.directorateName
```

Note: i didn't test it out so might need a bit of work.

Comment: errors because you're referencing a table not in the `FROM` clause (`employeeCourse` as opposed to `vwemployeeCourse`).  If this was a typo from the OP, this should work fine (although isn't perhaps as performant as possible).  If there really are two tables, this will generate the same wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

Use below query.

```
 Select max(vwemployee.directorateName), sum(t1) as t1, sum(t2) as t2
(select vwemployee.directorateName , 0 as t1 ,count(vwemployee.directorateName) as t2
UNION 
select vwemployee.directorateName,count(vwemployeeCourse.employeeId) as t1 , 0 AS t2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
SELECT vwemployee.directorateName AS dN, COUNT( vwemployeeCourse.employeeId ) AS t1, t2
FROM vwemployee
    JOIN vwemployeeCourse ON vwemployee.directorateName = vwemployeeCourse.directorateName 
    LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT vwemployee.directorateName AS ecdN, COUNT( vwemployee.directorateName ) AS t2 
            FROM vwemployee
                JOIN employeeCourse ON vwemployee.Id = employeeCourse.employeeId 
            GROUP BY  vwemployee.directorateName
            ) AS EmployeeCount
        ON dN = ecdN
GROUP BY vwemployee.directorateName
```

I have re-formatted your query to replace old style join syntax with ANSI-Joins